# Select Top n rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL result set that looks similar to this, and ordered by STYLE:

```
STYLE     |     CUSTOMER     |     SIZE     |      COLOUR      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
A               DWTG               S               BLUE
B               DWTG               S               RED
C               DWTG               S               GREEN
C               DWTG               M               GREEN
D               DWTG               S               ORANGE
D               DWTG               M               ORANGE
D               DWTG               L               ORANGE
```

Now, I need to split this result set and get the first 1000 rows. No problem, I can use `TOP 1000`.

My problem is, with the example above, if I wanted, say the top 3 rows, because `STYLE` has `C` repeated at the next row, I need to include this as well (so I would actually have 4 rows).

Example above, I would want the result set to look like:

```
STYLE     |     CUSTOMER     |     SIZE     |      COLOUR      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
A               DWTG               S               BLUE
B               DWTG               S               RED
C               DWTG               S               GREEN
C               DWTG               M               GREEN
```

This has come about because an ERP we are importing data into has a file size limit, so I need to split my result set into smaller files, but I need to keep the same records (same value in STYLE) together.

I was thinking a window function of some sort that dynamically adds a number to the `TOP n` based on if the next row has the same style.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show a sample of what you want the output to be?

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you want this:

```
select top 3 with ties *
from yourtable
order by style
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3bfd3/1)

Edit #1: See an updated [sql fiddle with your additional data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7101d/1)

Result:

```
| STYLE | CUSTOMER | SIZE | COLOUR |
------------------------------------
|     A |     DWTG |    S |   BLUE |
|     B |     DWTG |    S |    RED |
|     C |     DWTG |    S |  GREEN |
|     C |     DWTG |    M |  GREEN |
```

Comment: Just having a read about this, but it looks like this might work. My output has around 20 columns though, how do I specify using the `with ties` which column I want it to keep together?

Comment: @Lock It will use whatever column(s) you order by to tie the rows together, in this case just `style`.

Comment: @Lock can you add a couple of the other columns to your question, so that nobody is chasing a moving target?

Comment: @Lock thanks for updating the question. Now, did you *TRY* the query?

Comment: This looks like it will do exactly what I want. So if I order by only the column that I want to keep together in my queries, it will keep those together. Is there something similar in oracle? I'm using SQL server, so no problem, just didn't think there would be a standard function in SQL server that would do what I want!

Comment: @Lock see my edit with a new sql fiddle, the results are the same. :)

Comment: +1. Wish I could +1 again for `WITH TIES` and raising awareness.

Comment: That all said, the DENSE_RANK() alternative in the other answer will likely be more adaptable to getting the *next* 3 styles. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand agreed. windowing functions are better for that

Comment: Thankyou guys.. exactly what I want!

Comment: OK just another quick spanner to throw in the works.. this works perfect for my next query.. but my problem is, is that I am going to have 3 queries. I won't know what rownumber, or where to start on my next 2 queries (as I won't know where I left off). I think the window function might be better in this respect.

Comment: I had no idea that there was such a thing as with ties :)  Awesome

Comment: @Lock if you want to page the data then you will want windowing functions.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this using DENSE_RANK():

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   STYLE,
                        CUSTOMER,
                        DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY STYLE ) AS d_rank
               FROM     dbo.x
             )
    SELECT  STYLE,
            CUSTOMER
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   d_rank <= 3;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx